# How do you refactor C# code that returns a List<T>?

Tags: c#, api, refactoring, blazor

I find that I am repeating this code several times and would love some assistance refactoring it properly. How would I go about passing in the list of type that I am expecting to get back from the call?

```
masterData.PatternData = await GetMeetingData();
masterData.PatternDataDays = await GetMeetingDays();



    private async Task<List<MeetingPatternData>> GetMeetingData()
    {
        var retVal = new List<MeetingPatternData>();
        try
        {
            var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("ServerAPI");
            retVal = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<MeetingPatternData>>("MeetingTimeManager/GetPatterns");
        }
        catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)
        {
            exception.Redirect();
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    private async Task<List<MeetingPatternDays>> GetMeetingDays()
    {
        var retVal = new List<MeetingPatternDays>();
        try
        {
            var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("ServerAPI");
            retVal = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<MeetingPatternDays>>("MeetingTimeManager/GetDays");
        }
        catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)
        {
            exception.Redirect();
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable parts are the return type and the URI, so if you declare your method like this:

```
private async Task<List<T>> Get<T>(string requestUri)
{
    try
    {
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("ServerAPI");
        return await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<T>>(requestUri);
    }
    catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)
    {
        exception.Redirect();
    }
    return new List<T>();
}
```

Then you can call like this:

```
masterData.PatternData = await Get<MeetingPatternData>("MeetingTimeManager/GetPatterns");
masterData.PatternDataDays = await Get<MeetingPatternDays>("MeetingTimeManager/GetDays");
```

I've removed this part:

```
var retVal = new List<MeetingPatternData>();
```

Because your allocating a `List` unnecessarily.

You should probably also be returning an `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `List<T>` based on the philosophy of using the most restrictive type necessary to do the job, unless the caller needs to manipulate the returned data.